# Event handlers not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code and it is not getting triggered on the required actions, when I take out the first 2 `$("body").on` functions, the third one ie. (`$("body").on("click", '.upvote', function(event){`) gets triggered. When I put everything back in nothing works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //function 1
    $("body").on("change", '.select', function (event) {
        $('.row.replace').empty();
        $('.row.replace').append("<br><br><br><br><p align='center'><img id='theImg' src='/media/loading1.gif'/></p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>");
        var filter = $(this).find(":selected").attr("name");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/filter_home/" + filter + "/" + "TrendingNow" + "/",
            data: {
                'name': 'me',
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{% csrf_token %}'
            },
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('.row.replace').html("mem");
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        }); //end ajax
        return false;
    }); //end onchange

    //function 2
    $("body").on("click", '.sorter', function (event) {
        $('.row.replace').empty();
        $('.row.replace').append("<br><br><br><br><p align='center'><img id='theImg' src='/media/loading1.gif'/></p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>");
        var sort = $(this).attr("name");
        var filter = $('.select').find(":selected").attr("name");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/filter_home/" + filter + "/" + sort + "/",
            data: {
                'name': 'me',
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{% csrf_token %}'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.row.replace').html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        }); //end ajax
        return false;
    }); //end onclick

    //function 3
    $("body").on("click", '.upvote', function (event) {
        var x = $(this).attr("name");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/upvote/" + x + "/",
            data: {
                'name': 'me',
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                var y = "vote-count" + x;
                $('i[class= "' + y + '"]').text(json.vote_count);

                //flip button
                $('.flip' + x).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert("oops, something went wrong! Please try again.");
            }
        }); //and ajax  
        return false;
    }); //end onclick   
}); //end ready
```

Comment: what kind of errors do u get?

Comment: With some markup, we might be able to replicate/test/debug etc.

Comment: What is `'{% csrf_token %}'` vs this later: `'{{csrf_token}}'`?

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Do each of the functions work individually?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work again, there are no errors in the console, clicks and actions don't trigger anything, only the third function works individually, and I have jquery included in the header

Answer (score -1):

The event handlers (functions 1,2,3) are all returning false. This stops the event from bubbling up the DOM. I'm guessing that they're not being triggered as expected because the first function to handle the event is stopping the propagation. Test this by removing the return statement.

Alternatively, you can try scoping the delegated event handler closer to the target.

Comment: If this were the case, the first one should still work when all three are in place . . .